# jQuery: load pages with ajax, caching, clean URLs and back button support

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance

I'm building a website with 5 pages. Some the pages are very content-heavy (100+ images), others are very light-weight (a couple of paragraphs of text).

I am looking for a jQuery solution (maybe there is a plugin?) that uses jQuery's [.ajax() method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to load the new pages when the user clicks the navigation. To be precise:

- On click, the page's content fades out
- Once loaded, the desired page's content fades in
- The browser bar updates with a [clean URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL)
- The back button functionality is maintained
- The content of the first page is cached so that the HTML, JS and Images of the first page appear quickly when the user navigates back. I.e. no new ajax call is necessary. I know jQuery's .ajax() supports caching when you use the Promise functionality as described in [this video](http://youtu.be/bGlHjDWTYng?t=11m18s) (around 11:00)

Here's what I have so far:

I found [Ajaxify](https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify), a collection of scripts which is supposed to do more or less what I am aiming for. I am not sure whether it is a robust solution and supports caching and clean URLs, though. Does anybody have experience with it?

I have a start page (index.php) and another page (info.php) with this markup:

```
<nav class="nav-1">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Index</a></li>
        <li><a href="info.php">Info</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="page">
    <p>This is the content area. Its content is to be replaced via Ajax.</p>    
</div>
```

*Update: Added more details on the state of the project*

Comment: You didn't come up with a concrete solution that you are working on — basically you are simply listing the features you want to achieve, but show no work done on your part besides that. In SO we prefer to work with questions that show some effort invested in terms of writing code (which is preferably validated but still has problems functioning).

Comment: Thanks, Terry. I have a lot of work done. Sorry if I haven't made that clear enough. I thought it would be easier if I describe the problem in an abstract way. I will update the post so it reflects the state of the project.

Comment: I added more details to provide a more concrete example to work with.

Answer (score -1):

Try turbolinks or pjax.

https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/

http://pjax.heroku.com

The only missing part is the fade in / fade out callbacks, which can be inserted with listen events for either.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Unfortunately it seems like both of these solutions depend on Rails on the server side. I should have mentioned that on the server side I have a relatively standard PHP based CMS running which serves the HTML.

Comment: Neither is framework dependent. Just use the pjax js file along with jquery or the turbolinks js file (no jquery required). Keep in mind, you have to tailor the server side response to serve the XHR request appropriately.